# Interactive Responses in CLI

Tags: python, bash, shell, command, command-line-interface

I am struggling to write a command using either `python` or a `bash` script that inputs responses to commands.

For example, I may install a program using a command and it responds with the `Y/n` prompt. I know there is a `-y` flag for the command `sudo apt install`.

However, I also want to be able to enter and retype passwords after doing the `sudo passwd ubuntu` command.

How do I address this in a program?

Comment: `Expect` is one tool designed for such purposes.The other one is `yes` command